# How to prevent fast orientation changes in Android?

Tags: android, orientation

How can I prevent fast one after another orientation changes in Android? I only want to allow the user to change the orientation if the last orientation change has finished and all tasks in my Activity are done.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the configuration changes the app handles will allow the app to control orientation changes. These are specified in the [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config). Just hold on to the last configuration change then apply at an opportune time in the app.